# Add scroll bar to Composite which uses GridLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I want to add vertical scroll bar to the screen that comes out of the below code. can you please suggest how it can be done?

```
public class SampleDialog extends TrayDialog {

public SampleDialog(final Shell shell) {
    super(shell);
    this.shell = shell;

}


@Override
public void create() {
    super.create();

}

@Override
protected Control SampleDialog(final Composite parent) {
    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    parent.setLayout(layout);

    createSampleText(parent);

    createSampleCombo(parent);
}
} 

where:
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TrayDialog;
org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
```

org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) as the main parent for all your child controls in the dialog.

Some helpful [snippets can be found here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#scrolledcomposite).